# Preciso que uma consulta em SQL só retorne um dado,quando o outro não existir

Tags: mysql, sql

Por exemplo, tenho uma tabela, com 2 colunas, Nome e Letra. A tabela Nome, são inserido os respectivos nomes, e a tabela letra, só aceita 3 letras, A, B e C.

O mesmo nome pode ter as 3 letras. Eu queria fazer um select somente quando um nome possuir só a letra A. Se o mesmo possuir a letra A e também a B, não quero que apareça no select. Mais ou menos assim. Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço!!

Comment: Ou até `WHERE 'A' IN (letra_1, letra_2)`

Comment: Perdão eu expliquei errado. Tentei reformular a pergunta mas não consegui. Segue exatamente o que eu quero:

Por exemplo, tenho uma tabela, com 2 colunas, Nome e Letra. A tabela Nome, são inserido os respectivos nomes, e a tabela letra, só aceita 3 letras, A, B e C.

O mesmo nome pode ter as 3 letras. Eu queria fazer um select somente quando um nome possuir só a letra A. Se o mesmo possuir a letra A e também a B, não quero que apareça no select. Mais ou menos assim. Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, imagino que essa query deva servir:

```
SELECT TABELA.*
  FROM TABELA
  LEFT JOIN TABELA T2
    ON T2.NOME = TABELA.NOME
   AND T2.LETRA IN ('B', 'C')
 WHERE TABELA.LETRA = 'A'
   AND T2.NOME IS NULL
```

Não tenho MySQL instalado pra testar, então pode haver alguma diferença no dialeto.

Comment: Pode testar no db-fiddle.com se quiser.

Comment: Interessante esse _db-fiddle.com_, testei lá e funcionou certinho, valeu Anderson!